# Simple boat in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm creating a simple controllable boat in Actionscript and have gotten it to go foreward, turn left and right but can't get it to turn around. I want the boat to go in the direction it's pointing.

```
function moveBoat(event:Event):void
{
    if(rightKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.x += speed;
        player_mc.rotationZ += speed;
    }
    if(leftKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.x -= speed;
        player_mc.rotationZ -= speed;

    }
    if(upKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.y -= speed;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

```
function moveBoat(event:Event):void
{
    if(rightKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotationZ += turnFactor;
    }
    if(leftKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotationZ -= turnFactor;
    }
    if(upKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.x += speed * Math.cos(player_mc.rotationZ * Math.PI / 180);
        player_mc.y -= speed * Math.sin(player_mc.rotationZ * Math.PI / 180);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function moveBoat(event:Event):void
{
    if(rightKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotation += turnFactor;
    }
    if(leftKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotation -= turnFactor;
    }
    if( upKeyIsDown )
    {
        // convert our rotation to radians first
        var rads:Number = player_mc.rotation * ( Math.PI / 180.0 );
        player_mc.x += speed * Math.cos( rads );
        player_mc.y += speed * Math.sin( rads );
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `player_mc.y -= ...`, set `player_mc.y += ...` and it'll work. Like I mentioned in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function moveBoat(event:Event):void
{
    if(rightKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotationZ -= turnFactor;
    }
    if(leftKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.rotationZ += turnFactor;
    }
    if(upKeyIsDown)
    {
        player_mc.x += speed * Math.cos(player_mc.rotationZ * Math.PI / 180);
        player_mc.y -= speed * Math.sin(player_mc.rotationZ * Math.PI / 180);
    }
}
```

I can't test the code right now, but that should be enough to explain the idea. What I'm doing differently is using the Left and Right keys to steer the ship (by changing its angle) and moving it in the direction it's pointing in when clicking the Up key.

When moving the ship you can't simply move it on the X and Y axis by an amount, you need to also take into account the orientation of the ship. For that, use the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer but now when up is pressed the boat only goes left or right, depending on how far it has been rotated.

Comment: The rotationZ property uses degrees and the Math functions use radians. When calling the math functions, be sure to convert degrees to radians (player_mc.rotationZ * Math.PI / 180). If that doesn't work, please post the exact code you used.

Comment: Made some edits but still the up key moves the boat on the x axis

Comment: You have a typo (wrote "Math(" instead of "Math.cos(").

Comment: That typo was only here, I fixed it in my code but forgot to fix it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use some simple trigonometry to figure out how much to move the object on the X and Y axes. Create a right triangle where the boat is point A, it's speed is h, and the boat's orientation is angle A:

[image: right triangle]

Now use sine and cosine to figure out the lengths of the sides a and b. That's how far to move on the X and Y axes.

Answer (score -1):

TokPhobia almost had it right

```
private function _moveBoat(event:Event):void
{
    if( rightKeyIsDown )
        this.m_player.rotation += turnFactor;

    if ( leftKeyIsDown )
        this.m_player.rotation -= turnFactor;

    if( upKeyIsDown )
    {
        // convert our rotation to radians first
        var rads:Number = this.m_player.rotation * ( Math.PI / 180.0 );
        this.m_player.x += speed * Math.cos( rads );
        this.m_player.y += speed * Math.sin( rads );
    }
}
```

Btw, unless you're doing this in 3D, the `rotation` property will work just fine, you don't need to use `rotationZ`

Comment: It's actually working, you just need to change the rotation of your ship image. Flash takes a rotation of 0 as facing right, whereas your ship is designed as facing up (-90 in Flash rotation). Just edit your ship image to point right and you'll be fine